# Get DOM from external page using AJAX after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am working on a page that gets the DOM from an external page, but when the external page completely loads, then it gets updated once before its fully loaded. Let me explain it more clearly.

The order of the events goes like this:

- I make an AJAX request to **EXTERNAL PAGE**
- **EXTERNAL PAGE** fully loads and I get the DOM from success event
- *console.log()* prints "Vehicle A"
- Then **EXTERNAL PAGE** updates just once to reorder vehicles and make the "Vehicle B" to stay at the first position.

What I want is just this:

- Make an AJAX request to **EXTERNAL PAGE**
- Wait 1 second to let the page's javascripts update it
- Get the DOM of that new updated and fully loaded **EXTERNAL PAGE** so the vehicles order is correctly formed.
- *console.log()* prints "Vehicle B"

This is the simple code I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.vehicles.com/?q=vehicles',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var respuestaDOM = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");

        console.log(respuestaDOM.getElementsByClassName("vehicle")[0].innerHTML)
    }
});
```

This part of the code gets the first vehicle loaded:
`console.log(respuestaDOM.getElementsByClassName("vehicle")[0].innerHTML)`
So right now, it prints "Vechile A", but if you load the page manually, after its javascript loads, you could see that "Vehicle B" is at first. (The page is not real so don't try to test it)

I have been working on this one entire day, I have used ChatGPT and surfed every page on the internet with no success.

I think the solution is simple, use AJAX to make the request but wait just 1 second before get the DOM it seems to be impossible...

Thank you guys.